# Does not point to a Valid .jar

Tags: path, jboss, startup

Not Sure why I am getting this wrong path. Appreciate if anyone can help. On Windows 10 Enterprise Edition. Java Adopt JDK 11.06

```
2020-01-29 21:53:18,527 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
2020-01-29 21:53:23,794 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/sample-server error Read timed out
2020-01-29 21:53:28,421 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in **/C:/Windows/System32**/content/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-2.3.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2020-01-29 21:53:28,421 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /C:/Windows/System32/content/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2020-01-29 21:53:28,706 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in **/C:/Windows/System32/**content/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2020-01-29 21:53:28,753 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in /C:/Windows/System32/content/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2020-01-29 21:53:28,753 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in **/C:/Windows/System32/content/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.**
2020-01-29 21:53:28,753 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry serializer.jar in **/C:/Windows/System32/content/business-central.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.**
2020-01-29 21:53:31,482 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.business-central.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.as.domain-management") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2020-01-29 21:53:31,629 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment business-central.war
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are just warning messages. In your `MANIFEST.MF` you likely have the `Class-Path` attribute configured.

On a side note you probably shouldn't be using the internal `org.jboss.as.domain-management` module.

Comment: thanks,  for the feedback  On using the internal  org.jboss.as.domain-management , is this warning because I am starting up in  standalone mode

Comment: My assumption would be that you have a dependency on that module. Either in your `MANIFEST.MF` or in a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. In the manifest the key to the attribute is `Dependencies`.

Comment: Thanks, let me  review these xml files